# Display </ in a validation message

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a regular expression attribute to validate the user input against `</`. So if the user enters `</` in the input, then the following message should be displayed:
The following value is not allowed (

but the output is displayed like this:

```
<span id="CurrentPassword-error">The following values are not allowed (<!--)--></span>
```

I have used HTML.Decode and HTML.Encode and HTML.Raw but the same result.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an HTML encoder for special characters:

`< = &lt;
> = &gt;`

`<span id="CurrentPassword-error">The following values are not allowed (&lt;!--)--&gt;</span>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode string to be HTML safe.

```
<span id="CurrentPassword-error">The following values are not allowed (&lt;!--)--&gt;</span>
```

In razor you can use

```
 @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("(<!--)-->"));
```

Comment: I have used it but the same result